# Spring security login return method get

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/SC_A99_01_LoginIni").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/SC_A01_01_MasterRegisterEmployeeImport")
                .access("hasRole('0')");
        http.authorizeRequests().and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
        http.authorizeRequests().and().formLogin()
                // Submit URL
                .loginProcessingUrl("/SC_A99_01_Login")
                .loginPage("/SC_A99_01_LoginIni")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/SC_A99_01_Login")
                .failureUrl("/SC_A99_01_Login")
                .usernameParameter("loginId")
                .passwordParameter("password");
        http.authorizeRequests().and() //
                .rememberMe().tokenRepository(this.persistentTokenRepository()) //
                .tokenValiditySeconds(1 * 24 * 60 * 60); // 24h

    }
```

When I login success or error then it return a controller /SC_A99_01_Login with method GET, but i want return method POST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As both `defaultSuccessUrl` and `failureUrl` are defined for redirect, that means a new request will be made from the web browser after successful login or failure login.

```
 .defaultSuccessUrl("/SC_A99_01_Login")
 .failureUrl("/SC_A99_01_Login")
```

And if you don't want to make a new `GET` request from web browser, you can try another set

```
.successForwardUrl("/SC_A99_01_Login")
.failureForwardUrl("/SC_A99_01_Login")
```

which it will not make the web browser to send another request, but forward the same context to the new URL.